# How to build chrome extension css files before publishing?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browserify

I build a simple chrome extension and would like to publish it.

The problem is, I don't know how to proceed with some css files.

I used browserify and yarn to install bulma.

in my `main.js` I got the following line:

`import Styles from './styles.css'`

and the first line of styles.css looks like this:

`@import '../node_modules/bulma/css/bulma.css';`

Here's my **build** command from `package.json`

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=production browserify -g envify -t cssify src/main.js  | uglifyjs -c warnings=false -m > dist/build.js
```

and my index.html (popup.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="dist/build.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It works fine if I build it locally. But the only file generated is src/build.js. If I delete node_modules folder, the popup obviously look not good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up doing the following:

`yarn add browserify-css --dev`

https://github.com/cheton/browserify-css

then add the following to build command

`-t [ browserify-css --minify=true --output dist/bundle.css]`

full command:

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=production browserify -g envify src/main.js -t [ browserify-css --minify=true --output dist/bundle.css ] | uglifyjs -c warnings=false -m > dist/build.js
```

then just update index.html/popup.html with

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/bundle.css">`

Answer (score 1):

You either switch to sass and use something like Gulp together with sass for Bulma and compile your sass files together with your node_modules. The script below compiles down sass/scss style files using gulp-sass.

Or, since bulma seems to use `css-loader`(haven't looked this up) you can use the [extract-loader](https://github.com/peerigon/extrac) to extract css and html from your bundle file.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var $    = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

// Set your build paths here
var sassPaths = [
  'node_modules/some-library/scss/', // node modules
  'scss/' // your style files
];

gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('scss/app.scss') // where you've imported all your own style files
    .pipe($.sass({
      includePaths: sassPaths,
    })
      .on('error', $.sass.logError))
    .pipe($.autoprefixer({
      browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'ie >= 9']
    }))
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('/css'));
});
```

Then in your `package.json` you can set up a build script e.g. `"buildcss": "gulp sass",`